# how to add onclick event in HTML which should pop-up text container

Tags: html

I am new to HTML .I have a button in pop-up window, clicking on which should display some stored data.

> Window.Open() is used to open the pop-ups with URLs.

But Is it possible to display a text container which will display some stored data as a pop-up within pop-up? Could someone please clarify.

Comment: You can write HTML into the returned window.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a window.open that contains another html file... which would then has a popup as well (if that's what you meant).
Like: window.open("http://stackoverflow.com");